# Static, define, and const in C

Tags: c, static, constants, c-preprocessor

I've read that static variables are used inside function when one doesn't want the variable value to change/initialize each time the function is called. But what about defining a variable static in the main program before "main" e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static double m = 30000;

int main(void)
{
value = m * 2 + 3;
}
```

Here the variable m has a constant value that won't get modified later in the main program. In the same line of thought what difference does it make to have these instead of using the static definition:

```
const double m = 30000;
```

or

```
#define m 30000  //m or M
```

and then making sure here to use double operations in the main code so as to convert m to the right data type.

Comment: Thank you to all for the interesting answers. So I think the best thing in my case is to have static const double = 30000 .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
static double m = 30000; 

double foo(double x, double y) {
    return x/m + y;
}
```

This doesn't win you anything.  A copy of m has to be made to do the computation.
Also if you do:

```
double bar( double x, double y) {
     m += x + y;
     return  m;
}
```

Then all calls to bar will change m.
Static variables outside of functions (or classes) are really global variables with file scope.  Other files can't get at them by extern

Static variables inside a function are still like global variables, except that even other functions in the same file can't see them directly.

```
const double m = 30000;
```

This is better and in many cases best.  If the compiler sees this global const and then sees a reference to m then it knows that rather than generate code to load the value from where ever it is (which likely requires loading a literal address into a register first) to a register or stack position to do computations it can just make a register be 30000 or sometimes generate an instruction with 30000 encoded right in there.

The down side to this is that the compiler has to assume that other souce files will want to read m and has to actually store a copy as a variable (but a constant variable) in the object file.

I'm not sure if it is standard but you can sometimes do `extern const double m = 30000;` and the compiler will use 30000 to optimize and assume that another file actually has a copy of m that will be stored in the executable.   You can also do `static const double m = 30000;` and the compiler can assume that no one else will expect that a copy of m is stored in the object code generated from this source file.

Doing

```
#define m 30000
```

is more risky.  You will not get a warning or error if previously there was another m declared as a variable, constant, or function.  Also, for preprocessor macros like this it is easy to mess up.
For example:

```
#define BASE_ADDRESS 48
#define MY_OFFSET  9
#define MY_ADDRESS  BASE_ADDRESS+MY_OFFSET
...
  return MY_ADDRESS*4;
```

Yes, this is a stupid example, but what this looks like after the preprocessor gets done with it is

```
...
  return 48+9*4;
```

Which is

```
 return 48+(9*4);
```

And that's not what you probably wanted.

Another place where macros are bad is when you have large constants, such as strings.  Strings require that they be addressable by pointer and are more difficult to optimize away than integers and floating point literal or constant numbers.  You could easily make a very large program if you had lots of stuff like:

```
#define JIM "Jim"
#define JOHN "John"
```

and then used JIM and JOHN all over your programs because the compiler might not be able to see that you really only needed the strings "Jom" and "John" once in the program.

That being said, it is not uncommon to see constants being declared like that, and often they are properly done that way by people who know what they are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation. So if I have all codes in a single file, then static const double m = 30000 is the best answer I presume.

Comment: All compilers will recognize two string literals being identical and will store them only once.

Comment: In some cases you have to do with `define` instead of `const`. `static const uint8_t ARRAY_SIZE = 16U; uint8_t array[ARRAY_SIZE]` does not work because `ARRAY_SIZE` is not an explicit constant value. Same with `const uint8_t SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60U; const uint16_t SECONDS_PER_HOUR = 60U * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;`, it does not work. Which is a big big shame.

Answer (score 7):

`static` means that the variable will have static storage duration, and local visibility. In this case, it's being used for the "local visibility" part of that -- i.e. it means that `m` is visible only within this translation unit (essentially this file after it's prepocessed).

Answer (score 5):

`static` for an object declared outside a function merely makes the object local to the translation unit (i.e. it can't be accessed from other `.c` files). It doesn't make it constant. That it was `const` is for. They are orthogonal so you can have one or the other or both.

e.g.

```
static const double m = 5;
```

The `#define` declares a macro which (in this case) can be used as a constant value. There's no object, so `const` doesn't apply as there's not object to be changed. As a consequence, you also can't take the address of a macro.

Comment: Just to add a little: `const` and `static` aren't quite as orthogonal in C++ as they are in C. In C++, a `const` variable defined outside a function is also `static` by default.

Comment: @Jerry: Sure, but this is a C question and a beginner question, so it's probably a detail that isn't worth complicating the answer with.

Comment: Is orthogonal the right word? Or did you mean mutual? as u said we can either one or the other or both.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: I meant orthogonal. Whether an object has internal or external linkage (i.e. what `static` does) is independent of whether it is `const`.

Comment: Thanks. When I thought of orthogonal, I thought of orthogonal vectors where 1 component has no effect on the other orthogonal component :).

Answer (score 5):

When you write `const double m=3000;` you are telling the compiler to create a symbol `m` in the object file that can be accessed from other files. The compiler may inline the value of `m` in the file where it is defined, but the symbol still **has** to be allocated for the purposes of separate compilation.

When you write `#define m 3000` you are just using a syntactic convenience for writing the same constant in several places in the source file.

Answer (score 3):

If the value of `m` has to stay the same forever, then of course you can either use

```
static const double m = 30000;
```

or

```
#define m 30000
```

Just note that in C `const` objects have external linkage by default, so to get the equivalent `const` declaration you have to use `static const`, not just `const`.

Also note that in C language `const` objects are not *constants*, but rather "constant variables". If you need a true *constant* (i.e. an entity that forms *constant expressions*), you have to use either `#define` or enum constant.

The latter is normally an issue with integral constants only. In your case of a `double` the approach with `[static] const` might work best.

Answer (score 2):

> ... change/initialize each time the function is called

You use the words "change" and "initialize" as though they were the same, but they aren't

```
void f(void) {
  static int a = 0;
  a++; // changed!
  printf("%d\n", a);
}

int main(void) {
  f(); f();
}

/* 
  # 1
  # 2
*/
```

When at file-scope (outside functions) `static` does not mean "const" as in "static value", but it means that the identifier can only be referred to in that translation unit.

So your first `m` without `const` can still be changed. Only `const` guards against changes. But if you omit `static` then if you link in a library or another object file that has the same non-static identifier at file-scope you will get conflicts at link-time.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` is a preprocessor operation and will cause all occurrences of `m` to be replaced by `30000` before the compilation phase happens. The other two examples are bona fide variables. The `static` variable exists in the translation unit in which it is declared and *can be modified*. The `const` variable is read-only.

Answer (score 1):

In the toplevel scope `static` means that the variable (or function) cannot be accessed outside this source file - it won't be made available to the linker, and won't cause any name conflicts when linked in.  It has no effect on whether a variable is constant or not - in fact, such variables are often specifically non-constant so that initialization can be cached.

The difference between using `const` and `#define` is that the former allows the compiler to type-check your usage of a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that with #define you leave the type system. The preprocessor has no notion of type safety, scope etc. So e.g. if you later try to write a loop like

for (int m = 0; m < size; m++) { ... }

you are up to a nasty surprise...

Also if you use #defines, you will only see the value of 30000 when debugging your code, not the name `m`. Which does not seem to make a big difference in this case, but when using meaningful constant and variable names, it does indeed.

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting to know this debugging tip.