# What is the difference between global variables and #define in c

Tags: c, global-variables, c-preprocessor

Whats the reason why there are 2 opportunities :

1. global variables
2. symbolic constants with `#define` ?

So I know what `#define` does but I don't know what the difference in use is.
Which situation do I must have thus I'm able to decide myself upon the right opportunitie? What is one of the opportunities able to do what the other one doesn't ? I hope that I could clarify what I mean.

Comment: Global variables can be accessed and edited from everywhere. #define constants can't be edited, just read. It has to do with thread safety and reentry of functions.

Comment: "*I know what #define does*" Sure? ;-) However, reading this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/ might help you get enlightened.

Comment: A `global` variable is a variable, you can change it's value unless you make it a `const`,`#define` is fixed value. It cannot be changed at all.

Comment: @GAURAVVERMA: It's not even necessarily a "value".

Comment: #define is handled by the preprocessor. It is just plain text substitution in a certain sense. In cases of errors where your #define directive is involved the compiler won't be able to figure it out, and you'll end up with "cryptic" error messages. Preprocessor directives have their place, but somtimes it's probably better to just stick to "`const globals`

Comment: Is this a duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1674032/694576 or to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2611063/694576

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, global variables can be edited from everywhere.

Basically, in the low level, a variable is stored in RAM memory and created after launching your application, it always has an address in RAM. Defines are just macros, your compiler will just replace your define names with its values in the compilation step.

`#define` can't be edited, it's just a macros. And `#define` is not just about values, you can define almost everything that you want, for example:

```
// Defining a constant
#define PI 3.14

// Defining an expression
#define MIN(x,y) ((x)<(y))?(x):(y)

// Defining a piece of code
#define STOP_TIMER \
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &__t1); \
    __lasttime = \
    (double) (__t1.tv_sec - __t0.tv_sec) + \
    (double) (__t1.tv_nsec - __t0.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
```

And, in most situations, defines are used to set some OS-specific or hardware-specific values. It's a really powerful thing, because it gives you the opportunity to change things dynamically in the compilation step. For example:

```
// Example with OS
#ifdef __linux__
    #define WELCOME_STRING "welcome to Linux!"
#else
    #define WELCOME_STRING "welcome to Windows!"
#endif

// Example with hardware
#if __x86_64__ || __ppc64__
    #define USING_64BIT
#else
    #define USING_NOT64BIT
#endif
```

Comment: Therefore the only  difference between a constant global variable and a macro is the memory (const global variable is stored in memory and a macro don't), isn't it ?

Comment: @Clock_9 Yeah that's one of the differences, but not the only. You can't store a piece of code in the ordinal variable, and you can't do some system-specific stuffs with variables.

Comment: @Clock_9 As for defines: if you define something like `#define PRINT_THE_HELLO_DEFINES printf("hello defines!\n");` and `void main(){ PRINT_THE_HELLO_DEFINES }`, then your code will be replaced like that: `void main(){ printf("hello defines!\n"); }`. So, defines are about replacing stuffs.

Answer (score 9):

Consider this small example

```
#define num 5
int number = 5;
```

`num` is a macro and `number` is a global variable.

One important difference is that `num` is not stored in the memory, `num` is just the substitute for 5, but `number` uses memory.

Also, macro's are preprocessor directives, their values cannot be changed like variables.

So, no doing

```
num = 6;
```

later in the code. You will have to use `#undef` to undefine it and define it again to change the value.

Comment: Macros can be redefined (after they are undefined using the `#undef` preprocessor directive).

Answer (score 2):

Global variables can be accessed and edited from everywhere. #define constants can't be edited, just read.

Examples:

- We use `#define ERROR 666` to define a programmer pre compile time constant for an error for the whole program.
- We use a global variable for a count of how many operations a function did and this value can be read by other functions as well.

There's no point to make the error as a global variable since it shouldn't be edited and you can't use the `#define x` as a counter.

Answer (score -4):

`#define` is declared on top of the code, it means before the declaration of the class. And it serves as to define (as the name says) a constant, that can be read but not changed.

A global variable can be accessed globally on the code, and at same time changed.

Comment: There are no classes in C.

Comment: (Don't know why this comment had been deleted) A pre-processor directive like `#define` can be put on each line of a file which is going to be fed to the C pre-processor.