# How to make a "global variable" with a table?

Tags: c

In my program, I need to use a "global variable" which is D[M] (where M is a constant defined in the preprocessor directives)

The problem is that in the function I have in the program, the prototype isn't using D[M] (while the function is using it)

So I thought "If they call it a global variable, it means that the table is a constant, right ?" but I can't find a way to make a constant (#define) with a table (#define D[M] or #define D[])

Do you guys know what did they (my professor) meant by saying "The program use a global variable D, which is a table of M integers" ?

Here's my program if it can help (it's mostly french but i think it's understandable) :

http://pastebin.com/0WfRxa3e

(The purpose of this program is to find wether or not ' n ' (or ' u ' in the function) is a prime number + if it's a perfect number)
It's not finished yet as I wanted to check if the "while" condition worked as I wanted to..

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please post code directly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The program use a global variable `D`, which is a table of `M` integers.

This is probably what is meant:

```
#define M 10
int D[M] = {0};
int main() {
  D[0] = 42; // can access array here, because it's a global variable
  return 0;
}
```

> If they call it a global variable, it means that the table is a constant, right?

Global variables are not necessarily constant (read-only).
Note that preprocessor macros (`#define ...`) and constants (`static const int ...`) are not quite the same thing.

For further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const
- [Static, define, and const in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2611063/1025391)

Comment: Thanks for your answer
So it means that, if I only need to read the table, I don't have to declare it in the prototype ?

And, "D[M] {0}" is in the preprocessor directives ?

Comment: @GianniGentile When you want to access (reading or writing) a non-const global array within a function's scope, you don't need to pass it via its parameter list. It is visible inside the function body, because it already is in the global scope.